# Why does dynamically populating a select drop down list element using javascript not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, internet-explorer-8

I have a <select> element that I dynamically populate with different values at runtime.

I use the code below to clear the <option> elements and then reload it with new ones. It works in Firefox 3.6.6 and Chrome 5.0.

```
function loadPickerFromObject(pickerControl, values) {
    pickerControl.empty();
    for (var nameProperty in values) {
        if (!$.isFunction(values[nameProperty])) {
            var option = $("<option></option>")
                .text(values[nameProperty])
                .attr("value", nameProperty)
                .appendTo(pickerControl);
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm not fond of writing javascript and try to stay away from it, if there is a better way of dynamically populating a <select> element from the properties of an object please show how)

It doesn't work in IE 8. When I debug using Visual Studio I can see that the new items were loaded correctly, but when I check the page they're not updated and display the old items.

[image]
[image]

What's up with that? It should display the elements displayed in the Text Visualizer window (first screenshot). Why is it not showing the new values?

Comment: I would say check your caching if it runs in all other browsers. IE is know to hold on to old data. Try a CTRL+F5 / deleting your internet cache and see if it displays the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the jQuery `empty()` function and it was calling `removeChild` internally. It seems that IE doesn't work reliably with `removeChild` called on a `<select>` element.

So I rewrote my `loadPickerFromObject` function to use the `createElement`, `add` and `remove` functions instead of jQuery's `$([html])`, `appendTo` and `empty` functions.

My code now works properly in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the add() method. So your code would look like:

```
function loadPickerFromObject(pickerControl, values) {
    pickerControl.empty();
    for (var nameProperty in values) {
        if (!$.isFunction(values[nameProperty])) {
            pickerControl.add("<option></option>")
            .text(values[nameProperty])
            .attr("value", nameProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer likes to cache data.

Try `CTRL + F5.`

And you can use `CTRL + SHIFT + DEL` to bring up the dialog where you can clear the cache explicitly.

If this makes a difference you may want to think about adding headers in to try stop this from happening. **For Example:**

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

By the sounds of it your making ajax requests for data?
**You can also try:**

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: Nope, no Ajax requests. I have a bulk chunk of JSON data when the page loads, and then at runtime I load subsets of that data into the drop down list. I don't think it is a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be even better if you will build one string of html and just append to the dom at the end.
instead of manipulating the dom every time.
something like this:

```
function loadPickerFromObject(pickerControl, values) {  
    pickerControl.empty();  
    var optionsHtml;

    for (var nameProperty in values) {  
        if (!$.isFunction(values[nameProperty])) {  
            optionsHtml += "<option value='" + nameProperty  + "'>" + 
                                values[nameProperty] + 
                           "</option>";
        }  
    }

    pickerControl.append(optionsHtml);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

GiddyUpHorsey is correct, the problem is with `removeChild`.
There is a very easy way to clear a `select` though.

```
mySelect.options.length = 0
```

So you could do this:

```
function loadPickerFromObject(pickerControl, values) {
    pickerControl[0].options.length = 0;
    for (var nameProperty in values) {
        if (!$.isFunction(values[nameProperty])) {
            pickerControl.add("<option></option>")
            .text(values[nameProperty])
            .attr("value", nameProperty);
        }
    }
}
```